How to get SESSIONS with UNNEST function in Google BigQuery?
I need to count how much sessions where received with such parameter.
But it gives too much of results after execution, I think it's because of UNNEST function. How can I count correctly sessions?
SELECT 
    event_date,
    event_name,
    device.category AS device,
    user_pseudo_id AS total_users,
    (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key='source').string_value AS source,
    (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key='medium').string_value AS medium,
    (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key='campaign').string_value AS campaign,
    (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key='page_title').string_value AS page_title,
    (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key='page_location').string_value AS page_location,
    (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key='ga_session_id').int_value AS ga_session_id,
    COUNT(distinct CONCAT(user_pseudo_id,(SELECT value.int_value FROM unnest(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id'))) as sessions,
    COUNT(*) AS event_count
FROM 
   `analytics_375018211.events_*`
GROUP BY
    event_date,
    event_name,
    device,
    page_title,
    page_location,
    source,
    medium,
    campaign,
    total_users,
    ga_session_id


An example of event_params column in the table from which I get it by using sql query
{

"event_params": [{
"key": "ga_session_id",
"value": {
"string_value": null,
"int_value": "1714136265",
"float_value": null,
"double_value": null
}
}, {
"key": "campaign",
"value": {
"string_value": "campaign",
"int_value": null,
"float_value": null,
"double_value": null
}
}, {
"key": "ga_session_number",
"value": {
"string_value": null,
"int_value": "1",
"float_value": null,
"double_value": null
}
}, {
"key": "page_title",
"value": {
"string_value": "title",
"int_value": null,
"float_value": null,
"double_value": null
}
}, {
"key": "page_referrer",
"value": {
"string_value": "/",
"int_value": null,
"float_value": null,
"double_value": null
}
}, {
"key": "source",
"value": {
"string_value": "source",
"int_value": null,
"float_value": null,
"double_value": null
}
}, {
"key": "medium",
"value": {
"string_value": "medium",
"int_value": null,
"float_value": null,
"double_value": null
}
}, {
"key": "page_location",
"value": {
"string_value": "/",
"int_value": null,
"float_value": null,
"double_value": null
}
}]
}

Could you please be more specific and provide the required output and the output you are currently getting? Also, what does the input data look like? Please how to ask questions on StackOverflow.

@Vikas Sharma
I need to get data from BigQuery and create a report in Looker Studio. The code I added above contains the data I need. But the problem is how to count the sessions. When I use the UNNEST function to retrieve data from the "event_params" column, the number of sessions shows a result that is 3 times higher than it should be. If the UNNEST function is not used, the sessions show the correct result.

@Vikas Sharma
I need to get the number of sessions correct

You can show event_params value examples.

@ValNik An example of event_params column in the table from which I get it by using sql query (added screenshot above)

Example as text in the previous version it was better.

@ValNik added as text
